# Not enough time for destructor to finish?

Tags: c++, mfc

Does this even make sense if I say the destructor is existing abruptly not getting the chance to finish up because the UI window has been canceled when all this is happening in the same (main) thread?

When I press 'cancel' in a dialog, I want to free the memory associated with the list time:

```
CMyListCtrl::~CMyListCtrl()
{
    ItemData* pItemData;
    int nItems = GetItemCount(); <- errors out here and it is called
    for(int i=0; i<nItems; i++)
    {
        pItemData = (ItemData*)GetItemData(i);
        if(pItemData != NULL)
            delete pItemData;
    }
}
```

My OnCancel() handler is following where

```
LONG CSetupDlg::OnCancel(UINT wParam, LONG lParam)
{
    ((CSetupDoc *)GetActiveDocument())->Exit();
    return 0;
}

void CSetupDoc::Exit()
{
    GetDocTemplate()->CloseAllDocuments(TRUE);
}
```

The destructor is called essentially because of the `CloseAllDocuments()` call but it gets blown in the middle when it is trying to clean up and I can't even step through it. If I comment `CloseAllDocuments()` call, then window never gets destroyed and destructor is never called, so the destructor is definitely tied to this function and they are obviously in the same thread.

Why does it assert as if the underlying window has magically disappeared or something?

The error message I get is `MyApp has triggered a breakpoint` and I can't step through it any further.

Comment: Please provide more code. Without seeing every line that is executed, it is hard to debug.

Comment: Please indicate (at the very least in the tags,) what you are working on.  It is almost certainly Windows, but then what environment? MFC? ATL?

Comment: I don't think the destructor is called until the window is destroyed, thus it's too late to access the control. I have no idea why this would be connected with `CloseAllDocuments`.

Comment: `if(pItemData != NULL)` - unnecessary. `delete` is defined as a no-op on null pointers, all implementations accept it.

Comment: Your question title "Not enough time for destructor to finish?" suggests you think there is a race condition. There isn't. Simply when the destructor is called, the dialog (and all of it's child windows) doesn't exist anymore as the answers already point out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting the correct answer that fixed the issue. We need to free the list memory in `LVN_DELETEITEM` message handler (Even `OnDestroy()` didn't work, the list was already gone by then).

```
void CMyListCtrl::OnLvnDeleteitem(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    LPNMLISTVIEW pNMLV = reinterpret_cast<LPNMLISTVIEW>(pNMHDR);
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here

    ItemData* pItemData = (ItemData* )pNMLV->lParam;
    delete pItemData;

    *pResult = 0;
}
```

As far as the destructor was asserting/not executing further is because `GetItemCount()` operates on list *window* but since it is already destroyed, the behavior is unknown.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you may not access functions of the list control from within the destructor.  I don't remember whether this is a rule or whether it is happening due to some other weird situation in your code.  It may be that as a rule, you cannot do that.

In any case, you probably want to try doing your cleanup in a handler for the `WM_DESTROY` message of the list control instead of the destructor of the list control.

Comment: That seems like it, I almost want to say I have seen this behavior sometime way back as well. But technically when control is destructor of the list control, it should still be not destroyed.

Comment: zar is right -- cleanup in your class override `CMyListCtrl::DestroyWindow`, then call `CListCtrl::DestroyWindow` when your cleanup is finished.  You usually don't do anything in an MFC destructor which would require a valid window because the `CWnd` object encapsulates data for, but is not equivalent to an actual window.

Comment: I  suggest you to put a breakpoint on the `WM_DESTROY` handler function you will add; then when it is hit, create a Data Breakpoint (on Breakpoints Pane) which condition is `listcontrol->m_hWnd` change. At some moment variable will get to be null and execution will pause there. Then you can step individually to each relevant step, so you will get a lot more grasp on how the whole process is happening. BTW, if you "can't even step through it", may be you have not he correspondent symbols loaded.

Answer (score 1):

You are waiting too long.  It's too late in a destructor.  At that point, the window handle (m_hWnd) is no longer valid and Windows has destroyed the window. The items in the list control have all been removed at this point.  As others have pointed out, add your own CMyListCtrl::OnDestroy() function and a ON_WM_DESTROY() macro to your CMyListCtrl message map. Put the cleanup code in the OnDestroy() function.

Comment: Tried that and while it doesn't assert there but GetItemCount() returns zero and the dialog has already disappeared still so it looks like list is already destroyed.

Comment: oh I remember now, it has to deleted on WM_DELETEITEM!

Comment: Usually, I don't do it the way you are doing it.  Usually, the collection exists outside of the lifetime of the control.  In that case, when I call SetItemDataPtr(), I am setting either an index, pointer, iterator, or other reference to an item in the collection that doesn't need to be cleaned up by the control.